# Verify the existence of a dictionary key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have this code snippet and I need to check the dictionary before accessing it.

How can I verify the existence of the key before trying to access it ?

```
foreach (var publication in publications)
            {
                var publicationLinks = links[publication.PublicationId];

                var litigationLink = publicationLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessoId.HasValue);
                if (litigationLink != null)
                {
                    litigationLinks[publication.PublicationId] = litigationLink.ProcessoId.Value;
                    continue;
                }
                var contactLink = publicationLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContatoId.HasValue);
                if (contactLink != null)
                {
                    contactsLinks[publication.PublicationId] = contactLink.ContatoId.Value;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use the ContainsKey() method.

Comment: I prefer TryGetValue to ContainsKey.  ContainsKey makes you repeat stuff.  Ends up looking like something in PHP

Comment: @JoelFan `ContainsKey` + `[]` also has a performance impact compared to `TryGetValue`

Comment: In my case the "links" is an ILookup.
In that case can I use Contains ()?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-5.0) method or try to retrieve the value associated to the key:

```
if (links.TryGetValue(publication.PublicationId, out LinkCollection links))
{
    ...
}
```

(assuming `links` is a `Dictionary<string, LinkCollection>` for instance)

Comment: Or out var then you don’t have to assume anything :)

Comment: In my case the "links" is an ILookup.
In that case can I use Contains ()?

Comment: @Dolla then you can use `Contains` instead of `ContainsKey`, but `TryGetValue` is not available. It's not an issue since `links[publication.PublicationId]` will return an empty enumerable in case the key is not present in the lookup, which emptiness can easily be detected with Linq's `Any`.